# Is there an equivalent of C++ STL templates in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, templates

Algorithm objects in VB.Net

Basically I would like to use vb.net as my only programming language, though I have been using Ada, Pascal and C++ for many years. I'd like to find out useful tools and programs, Even if I have to expose them as ".net" objects (I did it very long time ago with ATL templates)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the nearest .NET equivalent to the STL is `System.Collections.Generic` for the collection objects and `System.Linq` and the extension methods on `IEnumerable(Of T)` for the algorithms.  The .NET `IEnumerable(Of T)` is the equivalent of iterators in the STL.

.NET generics are somewhat more limited than C++ templates in that there is no support for duck-specializing.  Any `Sub`, `Function`, or operator called on a variable typed as a type argument for a generic must be available on `Object` or through a constraint on the type argument.  Generic arguments can be constrained to be derived from a particular class type, implement a particular interface type, be either a reference or value type, or have a default ctor.

Comment: I spent many years developing in C++, then several years in VB.NET, then back to C++. To this day I find VB's in-place collection transformations via IEnumerable to be both easier and more powerful than a lot of what C++ has to offer. C++ range and view are getting there, but still not fully baked. IMO. As Craig points out, you get a different set of weaknesses with .NET generics, but don't let the weaknesses blind you to the strengths.

Answer (score 0):

The VB.net version of templates is called [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/generic-types).

I'm not aware of a full equivalent to the STL, but there are some reasonably equivalent parts of it.  [Generic collections in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/collections) is a good place to start.